# Android Extended ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I created my own ListView class (extended with TouchEvent detection)

```
public class MyListView extends ListView{
private ScaleGestureDetector myScaleDetector;
private float myScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new myScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        myScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    private class myScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
            SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            int a=3; //just for breakpoint
        }
    }

}
```

this is how i define it in layout contacts_activity.xml

```
<com.my.aclient.ui.MyListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"/>
```

But application is getting RuntimeException on line where this contacts_activity.xml file is inflated

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.contacts_activity);
```

Error reported in Logcat stacktrace

> Binary XML file line #106: Error inflating class
>   com.my.aclient.ui.MyListView

When i use only ListView everything works perfectly. What could make this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a custom view, you must implement three different constructors:

```
View(Context context)
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
```

Then you simply delegate to `super()` for each of these. All of these constructors are necessary in order to inflate your view from an XML file.

A simpler solution would be to use a regular `ListView` and create a subclass of `View.OnTouchListener`. Then you just call `setOnTouchListener()` on the `ListView` from within your `onCreate()` method (or in `onCreateView()` if you are using fragments).